Not able to authenticate the AWS ECR repo on the EC2 instance
I have created an IAM role for the EC2 instance that has all the required permission to authenticate and pull the AWS ECR image, but every time I try to authenticate, it shows the following error:
"An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:sts::1224**:assumed-role/deshtestrole11/i-0462b0f*4 is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: * because no identity-based policy allows the ecr:GetAuthorizationToken action"
This is my IAM policy:
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:12243*****:repository/d***testecr"
        }
    ]
}

What could be the issue as I have the "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken" action allowed.

The issue lies in the IAM policy's resource specification for the ecr:GetAuthorizationToken action. The ecr:GetAuthorizationToken action requires permissions at the account level (* for the resource or a specific account ARN).
  {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                    "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                    "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                    "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                    "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                    "ecr:PutImage",
                    "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                    "iam:PassRole"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:12243*****:repository/d***testecr"
            }
        ]
    }

